# Unique elements inside each child element of XML based on condition

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My requirement is that there should be only one listingagent TAG for each role_type Primary inside each commercial tag.

```
<deal>
<commercial>
<party></party>
<party>
<role_detail>
    <role_type>Primary</role_type>
</role_detail>
<listingagents>
    <listingagent>1</listingagent>
    <listingagent>2</listingagent>
</listingagents>
</party>
<party>
<role_detail>
    <role_type>Secondary</role_type>
</role_detail>
<listingagents>
    <listingagent>1</listingagent>
</listingagents>
</party>
<party></party>
</commercial>
<commercial>


</commercial>
<commercial>


</commercial>
</deal>
```

If there are more than one I need to raise an error.

The code I tried is as follows

```
var duplicates = doc.Descendants("Commercial")
                                    .Select(c => c.Descendants("listingAgent"))
                                    .GroupBy(c => c.ToString())
                                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                    .Select(g => g.First())
                                    .ToList();


 if (duplicates.Any(c => c.Count() > 1))
{
   //show error
}
```

Comment: And what happened with the code you tried? (It's not clear why you're grouping, or why you're checking for counts twice.)

Comment: I am new to XML , I am not really sure if my code is correct. Even if there is one listingagent tag it is giving me duplicate error

Comment: Note that your description doesn't actually sound like it's enforcing *uniqueness* at all. Imagine you removed the `<listingAgent>2</listingAgent>` from the sample XML. That would then meet the requirement that "there should only be one listingAgent element inside each commercial element".  It's just that the same value for that element appears twice... those aren't the same conditions. Which are you *actually* interested in?

Comment: One listingAgent element inside each Commercial. That's all. I dont care about values

Comment: So despite the title, you're not actually looking for uniqueness at all.

Comment: Unique element names inside each child element. Not unique values.

Comment: Your requirement doesn't have *any* uniqueness in it though. `<commercial><a/><a/><a/><listingAgent>foo</listingAgent></commercial>` doesn't have unique element names but meets the requirement. `<commercial><a/><b/></commercial>` has unique element names but doesn't meet the requirement.

Comment: ok maybe i wasnt clear. There should be one and only one listing agent per commercial tag. No more no less.

Comment: Right. I suggest you edit your title to reflect that then. (And at that point, it's entirely unclear what the code you started with was trying to achieve... grouping the values of `listingAgent` elements isn't going to help. It may be worth stepping back and thinking about *why* you started down that route, to help you get to the right code yourself next time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your constraint is that there should be exactly one `listingAgent` element within each `commercial` element, that's very simple:

```
var broken = doc.Descendants("commercial")
                .Any(c => c.Elements("listingAgent").Count() != 1);
```

This *doesn't* ensure that elements are unique though. For example, given that requirement, this XML is fine:

```
<deals>
    <commercial>
       <listingAgent>1</listingAgent>
    </commercial>  
    <commercial>
       <listingAgent>1</listingAgent>
    </commercial> 
    <commercial>
       <listingAgent>1</listingAgent>
    </commercial>  
<deals>
```

Each `commercial` element here has exactly one `listingAgent` child element. They've all got the same value, but that isn't part of the stated requirement. If you want uniqueness, that's a different requirement - and one that could be independent of the number of `listingAgent` children. For example, this meets uniqueness but not the "exactly one child" requirement:

```
<deals>
    <commercial>
       <listingAgent>1</listingAgent>
       <listingAgent>2</listingAgent>
    </commercial>  
    <commercial>
    </commercial> 
<deals>
```

Comment: What does Any() here denote?

Comment: @BhumikaSanghvi: Without a predicate, it checks whether there are any elements in the sequence. With a predicate, it checks whether any elements in the sequence meet the criterion. (I've edited to use the second form - `foo.Where(predicate).Any()` is equivalent to `foo.Any(predicate)`.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanantion :)

Comment: @BhumikaSanghvi: With no more information than that, all I can do is say "I believe it does, according to the requirements you gave." You haven't said *anything* about how it supposedly doesn't work, so I can't help you any further.

Comment: I modified the question.. can you please check?

Comment: @BhumikaSanghvi: No, that's a very impolite thing to do. You ask a question, you get an answer. You can't just keep adding *completely new* requirements onto a question - that's a good way to put people off helping you. I suggest you roll back the edit, accept this answer to the question you asked, then ask a *new* question with the different requirements, after trying to use the answer here to help you do it for yourself. I worked hard to clarify the requirements before answering - for you to *then* change them afterwards is rude, IMO.

Comment: I didnt mean to offend you.